# How can I resolve "CALL rule is not operational" error when running custom policy on APIC?

Tags: policy, ibm-datapower, apiconnect, apic

I exported a policy from `DataPower` and imported it in `APIC`, it imported successfully but when I run it, I get the following error:

`1,20180917T153109.216Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,multistep,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0x80c00009,,request,"request webapi-policy-step-fw-invoke-rule #2 Calling rule var://context/policy/exec with input NULL and output policy-output-temp. failed: CALL rule is not operational" 1,20180917T153109.220Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,xslt,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0x80c00010,,request,"Processing of 'local:///isp/policy/apim.policy.end.xsl' stopped: CALL rule is not operational" 1,20180917T153109.221Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,multistep,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0x80c00009,,request,"request webapi-policy-end #1 xform: Transforming the content of NULL. The transformation local:///isp/policy/apim.policy.end.xsl is applied. The results are stored in NULL. failed: CALL rule is not operational" 1,20180917T153109.221Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,multistep,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0x80c00009,,request,"request webapi-policy-step-fw-invoke-rule #5 Calling rule var://context/policy/fw/call-rule with input NULL and output NULL. failed: CALL rule is not operational" 1,20180917T153109.221Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,multistep,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0x80c00009,,request,"request webapi-mpgw-request-fw #9 Calling rule var://context/policy/fw/call-rule with input NULL and output NULL. failed: CALL rule is not operational" 1,20180917T153109.221Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,mpgw,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0xd30003,,error,"Rejected by filter; SOAP fault sent" 1,20180917T153109.223Z,APIMgmt_863A6BF796,xsltmsg,error,mpgw,webapi,63241538,63241538,10.68.128.47,0x80000001,,error,"api-error-response multistep error"`

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0x80c00009 is unfortunately a quite "broad" topic but it all boils down to some problem within your rule making it invalid or to crash when running.
My guess is that the Rule is invalid...

Make sure the scripts (XSLT and/or GWS) compiles and that all INPUT, OUTPUT, PIPE, NULL are properly configured.

If you have access to the DataPower instance (or run a Docker instance on your local laptop) you can export the Processing Policy and import it and run it "stand alone" to make sure it works and no syntax/config errors occurs in it.

If you are running large messages you might need to tune the XML Manager as well.

Comment: I managed to resolve that error by checking the processing rule in the APIMgmt domain and found that the actions were missing. I exported and imported again but now I'm facing an "Unknown rule in CALL" error, the processing rule doesn't get created in the APIMgmt domain anymore